# Center image doc.addImage jspdf

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas` to take screenshot of my page and creating pdf of the images using jspdf. Now, my images are left aligned in the pdf document, I want it to be centered, how can I achieve it?

```
function pdfmaker() {

    var element = $("#timesheet");

    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.display = "block";
    var firstName = "<?php echo $fname?>";
    var lastName = "<?php echo $lname ?>";
    var startDate = "<?php echo $startDate?>";
    var endDate = "<?php echo $endDate ?>";

    html2canvas(element, {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


            var imgWidth = 297; //297
            var pageHeight = 297; //297  
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
            var heightLeft = imgHeight;

            // var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm',[1350, 1350]);
            var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [420, 297]); //420,297
            var position = 5; //0

            margins = {

                top: 20,
                bottom: 10,
                left: 45,
                width: 522
            };


            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;

            while (heightLeft >= 5) {
                position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
                doc.addPage();
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                heightLeft -= pageHeight;
            }

            doc.save(firstName + '_' + lastName + '_Summary_report_' + startDate + '_' + endDate + ".pdf");
        }
    });

    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.display = "none";

}
```

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes. Did that long time back. Thanks.

Comment: And what was the solution?

Comment: Maybe post the solution next time

Answer (score 1):

You need to define inside the `addImage()` method, using the coordinate parameters, see: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html

This is the only way you can do it. For this, I suggest you use the following method `doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();` to calculate the excess values ​​about the image width, which will be centered.

Comment: Thank you. I did that few years back, solution not at the top of my mind at all.